# ‘main’ is normally a non-static function ERROR

Tags: c, linker, getopt

There are two errors that show up:
main.c:80: warning: ‘main’ is normally a non-static function
main.c:88: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
and I cant't seem to find the problem... There number of curly braces is equal... What seems to be the problem?

```
   #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "main-getopt.h"


void print_usage_and_abort( const char *message )
{
    if( NULL != message )
        fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s\n", message );
    
    fprintf( stderr, "Usage: partitioner -n <nodes> [ -f <basename> ]\n\n" );
    exit( -1 );
}

void parsing (int argc, char **argv, struct Params *params)
{
        char error_message[256];

    params->nodes = 0;
    memcpy( params->filename_base, "output", strlen("output") + 1 );

    int opt;
    size_t len;
    int numarg;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:f:")) != -1) {
        int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-')
        {
            if (i+1 == argc || argv[i+1][0] == '-')
            {
                sprintf( error_message, "No Filename");
                    print_usage_and_abort( error_message );
            }
            if (argv[i][1] == 'n')
            {
                numarg = atoi( optarg );
                if( numarg < 1 || numarg > 2048 )
                {
                    sprintf( error_message, "Number of nodes agrument expects a number between 1 and 2048, actual %s", optarg );
                    print_usage_and_abort( error_message );
                }
                }
            else if (argv[i][1] == 'f')
                len = strlen( optarg );

                // limit to buffer capacity
                if( len >= MAX_FILENAME_BASE )
                {
                    sprintf( error_message, "Base filename parameter length is expected to be less than %d but is %d", (int)MAX_FILENAME_BASE, (int)len );
                    print_usage_and_abort( error_message );
                }
                else if(len<MAX_FILENAME_BASE)
                {
                    memcpy( params->filename_base, optarg, len + 1 );
                    break;
        }
        
        else
        {
                sprintf( error_message, "Unknown command switch %c", (char)optopt );
                print_usage_and_abort( error_message );
                break;
                }
    }
    
}
if( 0==params->nodes )
    {
        sprintf( error_message, "Number of nodes switch -n is required" );
        print_usage_and_abort( error_message );
    }
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct Params params;
    parse_arguments( argc, argv, &params );

    fprintf( stdout, "Parameters are:\n\tNumber of nodes:\t%d\n\tFilename base:\t%s\n\n", params.nodes, params.filename_base );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you indent this code properly, it is much easier to see that you are missing a } at the end of the parsing() function. (as well as braces missing in the `else if (argv[i][1] == 'f')` body.

Comment: There is one closing curly bracket missing somewhere - the number is not equals!

Answer (score 11):

I've edited indentation for you. Do you see now that somewhere in `parsing` function you've missed one closing bracket?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't closing bracket '}' at the end of the parsing function.