# C: main is normally a non-static function

Tags: c

I have this piece of code here and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609763/main-is-normally-a-non-static-function-error) so I guess it's about brackets. I even showed it to a tutor walking around, but he didn't have an idea either and said it actually looks ok.

Complete error message is:

> buch.c: In function 'insert_at_begin':
>
> buch.c: warning: 'main' is normally a non-static function [-Wmain]
>
> buch.c157.1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input }
>
> buch.c157.1: warning control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] }

NOTE: main function was actually given beforehand and shouldn't be changed. Also, a few functions were given in an extra file.

Code is as follows. (few functions were given in an extra file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "introprog_structs_lists_input.h"

#define MAX_STR 255

/* Bewirkt, dass statt 'struct _element' auch 'element' verwendet werden kann. */
typedef struct _element element; 

/* Bewirkt, dass statt 'struct _list' auch 'list' verwendet werden kann. 
 * Hier in einem geschrieben, so dass man auch 'list' innerhalb der 
 * struct-Definition selbst verwenden kann.  
 */
typedef struct _list { /* Separater Wurzelknoten */
    element *first;    /* Anfang/Kopf der Liste */
    int count;         /* Anzahl der Elemente */
} list;

struct _element {

    char title[MAX_STR];
    char author[MAX_STR];
    int year;
    long long int isbn;
    element *next;
};/* HIER struct element implementieren. */

/* Fuege ein Element am Anfang der Liste an, sodass das neue Element immer das
 * erste Element der Liste ist.
 * Wenn die Liste leer ist soll das Element direkt an den Anfang platziert
 * werden.
 *
 * first    - Erstes Element (bzw. Anfang) der Liste
 * new_elem - Neues Element das in die Liste eingefuegt werden soll.
 *
 * Gib einen Pointer auf den neuen Anfang der Liste zurueck.
 */
element *insert_at_begin(element *first, element *new_elem) {
    
    
    if(first){
        new_elem->next = first;
        first = new_elem;
        //first->count = count++;
        return first;/* HIER implementieren. */
}

/* Kreiere ein neues Element mit dynamischem Speicher.
 *
 
 
 * title     - Der Titel des Buches
 * author    - Autor des Buches
 * year      - Erscheinungsjahr des Buches
 * isbn      - ISBN des Buches
 *
 * Gib einen Pointer auf das neue Element zurueck.
 */
element *construct_element(char *title, char* author, int year, long long int isbn) {
    //element *new = malloc(sizeof(element);
    element *new = (element*) calloc(1, sizeof(element));/* HIER implementieren. */
    strncpy(new->title, title, MAX_STR-1);
    strncpy(new->author, author, MAX_STR);
    new->year = year;
    new->isbn = isbn;
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}

/* Gib den der Liste und all ihrer Elemente zugewiesenen Speicher frei. */
void free_list(list *alist) {
    
    element *elem = alist -> first;
    element *alt;
    while (elem != NULL) {
        alt = elem;
        elem = elem -> next;
        free(alt);
    }
    free(elem);
    free(alist);/* HIER implementieren. */
}

/* Lese die Datei ein und fuege neue Elemente in die Liste ein 
 * _Soll nicht angepasst werden_
 * */
void read_list(char* filename, list *alist) {
    element* new_elem;

    char* title;
    char* author;
    int year;
    long long int isbn;
    read_line_context ctx;
    open_file(&ctx, filename);
    while(read_line(&ctx, &title, &author, &year, &isbn) == 0) {
        new_elem = construct_element(title, author, year, isbn);
        alist->first = insert_at_begin(alist->first, new_elem);
        alist->count++;
    }
}

/* Erstelle die Liste:
 *  - Weise ihr dynamischen Speicher zu 
 *  - Initialisiere die enthaltenen Variablen
 * _Soll nicht angepasst werden_
 */
list* construct_list() {
    list *alist = malloc(sizeof(list));
    alist->first = NULL;
    alist->count = 0;
    return alist;
}

/* Gib die Liste aus:
 * _Soll nicht angepasst werden_
 */
void print_list(list *alist) {
    printf("Meine Bibliothek\n================\n\n");
    int counter = 1;
    element *elem = alist->first;
    while (elem != NULL) {
        printf("Buch %d\n", counter);
        printf("\tTitel: %s\n", elem->title);
        printf("\tAutor: %s\n", elem->author);
        printf("\tJahr:  %d\n", elem->year);
        printf("\tISBN:  %lld\n", elem->isbn);
        elem = elem->next;
        counter++;
    }
}

/* Main Funktion
 * _Soll nicht angepasst werden_
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    list *alist = construct_list();
    read_list(argc>1?argv[1]:"buecherliste.txt", alist);
    print_list(alist);
    free_list(alist);
    return 0;
}
```

Really starting to drive me nuts, hope someone can help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question because _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 3):

```
element *insert_at_begin(element *first, element *new_elem) {


    if(first){
        new_elem->next = first;
        first = new_elem;
        //first->count = count++;
        return first;/* HIER implementieren. */
}
```

You never close the body of the `if`. Should be:

```
element *insert_at_begin(element *first, element *new_elem) {


    if(first){
        new_elem->next = first;
        first = new_elem;
        //first->count = count++;
        return first;/* HIER implementieren. */
    }
}
```

You should also specify a return value for the cases when `first` is `false`. Like returning `NULL`.

Comment: Wow damnit. Thanks a lot.