# compiling in codeblock but not in hackerrank

Tags: c, string

My program is working fine  on code block and with no warning but when i am submitting my code to hackerrank it showing error

```
 solution.c: In function ‘main’:
 solution.c:21:6: error: ‘main’ is normally a non-static function [- 
 Werror=main]
 int  main()
  ^~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

this is my actual code which is simple question on data type and strings

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)+1 ); // +1 for the null-terminator
    // in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
int main(){
    int i=4.0,x;
    double d=4.0,y;
    char result[301],z[100];
    char* p=result;
    char s[50]="HackerRank ";
    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%lf ",&y);

    int sum1=i+x;
    double sum2=d+y;
    p=concat(s,z);
    printf("%d\n",sum1);
    printf("%lf\n",sum2);
    printf("%s",p);



      return 0;



}
```

Comment: Working fine you say? What is the variable `z` doing in `main`? Anyway, this error message looks like there's a bug in hackerrank software and you should talk to their tech support.

Comment: ^^^ generating UB :(

Comment: Yeah.. you need to understand what @n.m. is hinting at. Variables with automatic storage are not initialized in C.  You should also maybe look up how strlen() works.

Comment: Also, probably not related to your error, but you didn't `free()` the result of `concat()` after using it in `main()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are creating main inside main then also you can face same problem

Comment: If you're the OP, why answer from a different account?

Comment: thats my room partner not me

Comment: sorry i will change my username

Comment: Alright. :) Also, can you elaborate on the answer? I'm not seeing a second `main` in OP's code. Or are you saying that hackerrank wraps the code in one large `main` automatically?

Comment: please help me  i have a doubt and no one is helping me

Comment: see the comments in solution of some programmers dude
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204225/how-to-update-table-size-inside-hash-function/52204328?noredirect=1#comment91380616_52204328

Comment: That's a different question. What I'm saying that this answer is accepted, but I'm not sure what changes to the code it's suggesting to do.

Comment: if you can suggest me the answer of that different question i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
solution.c:21:6: error: ‘main’ is normally a non-static function [- Werror=main]
```

The error is usually caused by the mis-match between opening and closing brackets.
So check whether all your brackets match once again before compilation.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609763/main-is-normally-a-non-static-function-error) which mentions the same problem.

Comment: Given that the OP posted the full code, this isn't the problem. Rather seems like a bug in "hackerrank", whatever that is.

Comment: There are other errors too with the code. Like "invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*'" with malloc(). Not sure, how it is working fine on "code block".

Comment: @user846834 that isn't an invalid conversion for C; it would be for C++. C allows implicit conversions to/from `void *` with pretty much any other data pointer type. The OP's `malloc` invoke is preferred as-is for C programmers (without the `strlen` invokes, which I would personally have done differently).