# how to update table size inside hash function

Tags: c, data-structures, hash

I was learning how to implement Hash table but i am bit confused here in because in the book below code was available and i understood well enough the code, but inside book there was no definition of `HASH` function ,i know we have to define it by own ,but according the below code that was given give inside book `HASH` is taking two arguments wherever i used the `HASH` like in  `HashInsert` it is taking two arguments `index=HASH(data,t->size)` if  we assume that return type of `HASH` as int 
now for eg we can define `HASH` as

```
int HASH(int  data,int tsize){
return(data%7);
}
```

but according to my program how should i update `t->size`(table size) inside `HASH` function or how should i use that 
Please help me in proper implementation of the above `HASH` function

```
#define Load_factor 20
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Listnode{
 int key;
 int data;
 struct Listnode* next;
};
struct HashTableNode{
 int bcount;          /// Number of elements in block
 struct Listnode* next;
 };
struct HashTable{
 int tsize;          /// Table size
 int count;
 struct HashTableNode** Table;
};
struct HashTable* createHashTable(int size){
 struct HashTable* h;
 h=(struct HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(struct HashTable));
 h->tsize=size/Load_factor;
 h->count=0;

 h->Table=(struct HashTableNode**)malloc(sizeof(struct HashTableNode*)*h->tsize);
 if(!h->Table){
 printf("Memory Error");
  return NULL;
 }
 for(int i=0;i<h->tsize;i++){
 h->Table[i]->bcount=0;
 h->Table[i]->next=NULL;
 }
   return h;
 }

/// Hashsearch
int HashSearch(struct HashTable* h,int data){
  struct Listnode* temp;
  temp=h->Table[HASH(data,h->tsize)]->next;
  while(temp)     ///same as temp!=NULL
  {
   if(temp->data==data)
      return 1;
    temp=temp->next;
  }
    return 0;

}

int HashDelete(struct HashTable* h,int  data)
{
 int index;
 struct Listnode *temp,*prev;
 index=HASH(data,h->tsize);
 for(temp=h->Table[index]->next,prev=NULL;temp;prev=temp,temp=temp->next)
 {
    if(temp->data==data)
    {
        if(prev!=NULL)
             prev->next=temp->next;
         free(temp);
         h->Table[index]->bcount--;
         h->count--;
         return 1;
    }
 }

 return 0;

}
int HashInsert(struct HashTable *h ,int data){
 int index;
 struct Listnode* temp,*newnode;
 if(HashSearch(h,data))
    return 0;
 index = HASH(data,h->tsize);
 temp=h->Table[index]->next;
 newnode=(struct Listnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct Listnode));
 if(!newnode)
    return -1;
 newnode->key=index;
 newnode->data;
 newnode->next=h->Table[index]->next;
 h->Table[index]->next=newnode;
 h->Table[index]->bcount++;
 h->count++;
   return 1;
}
```

> i am just learning implementation of hashing so main is looking quiet weird

```
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *shouldn't!* I mean you shouldn't *modify* it.

Instead the function gets the size of the hash-table (the number of "buckets") so it can use it to create a bucket index from the hash value. This is typically done through modulo `%`.

So instead of a fixed [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) `7` you modulo with the size:

```
return(data%tsize);
```

Comment: In my structure `struct ListNode` i am making  a int type variable `key` but it is necessary to make that in the `struct Listnode` can we make that inside `HashTableNode` because when two or more items will be there in HashTableNode(that is when collision will be more in single table node) than we have to create more linked list node and every time inside that node `key` variable will  consume some memory if we can define that inside `HashTableNode`  than we can save memory
Please tell me what i mentioned above is correct because i am a beginner if Not then please correct me 
Thankyou

Comment: @david12345 With the code you currently show, `ListNode->key` is the bucket index, and is never used. Instead the hash-table key is the data, which makes the hash-table a *set*. Also, each bucket should be a list (for collisions) but the `HashListNode` should contain the key and the data itself, not a pointer to some other list. Unless I'm missing something, which I probably do since we don't have your requirements or design.

Comment: since `key` and `index`  are different so then why in my code they index is assigned to key ,that code was given  in a famous book of DS

Comment: I am confused in `key` and `index` because in my code key is assigned to index can you explain it

Comment: if there is a need to correct my code (if you think) please correct it 
No one is helping me i am fighting from the hashing for 3 days Please help me
Thank you sir